# How to get the percentage of reviews of each product by product id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento, parameters, magento2, product, review

For example, I have 5 5-star reviews, 3 2-star reviews and 2 1-star reviews, when var_dump on the screen, it will look like this:
50% 5-star reviews,
30% 2-star reviews,
20% 1-star reviews

Pls help me, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
protected $_reviewFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory
) {
    $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
}

public function getRatingSummary()
{
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
    return $ratingSummary;
}
```